# C++ Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, assertion

I've written my own list class for practice, here it is:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// A linked node structure.
template <typename T>
struct LinkedNode
{
    T data;
    LinkedNode<T>* next;
    LinkedNode<T>* prev;
};

// Class linked list.
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:

    // Constructor
    LinkedList()
    {
        mFirst = 0;
        mLast = 0;
    }

    LinkedList(const LinkedList& rhs)
    {
        mFirst = 0;
        mLast = 0;

        // Get a pointer to the first node of rhs.
        LinkedNode<T>* current = rhs.mFirst;

        // While not at the end of the rhs linked list.
        while( current != 0 )
        {
            insertLast( current->data );
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    // Destructor
    ~LinkedList()
    {
        destroy();
    }

    // Overload
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList& rhs)
    {
        // Check for self assignment
        if ( this == &rhs )
            return *this;

        // Get a pointer to the first node of rhs.
        LinkedNode<T>* current = rhs.mFirst;

        // While not at the end of the rhs linked list.
        while( current != 0 )
        {
            insertLast( current->data );
            current = current->next;
        }

        // Chain assignments a = b = c = d
        return *this;
    }

    // Check if list is empty.
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if( mFirst == 0 && mLast == 0 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    // Return first and last nodes.
    LinkedNode<T>* getFirst() { return mFirst; };
    LinkedNode<T>* getLast()  { return mLast;  };

    void insertFirst(T tData);
    void insertLast(T tData);
    bool insertAfter(T tKey, T tData);
    void removeFirst();
    void removeLast();
    void remove(T removalCandidate);
    void destroy();

private:

    LinkedNode<T>* mFirst;
    LinkedNode<T>* mLast;
};

template <typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::insertAfter(T tKey, T tData)
{
    if( isEmpty() ) return false;

    // Get a pointer to the front of the list
    LinkedNode<T>* current = mFirst;

    // Loop until we find the tKey (the value of the node to insert after)
    while( current->data != tKey )
    {
        // Hop to the next node.
        current = current->next;

        // Test if we reached the end, if we did we didn't find the node to insert after (tKey)
        if( current == 0 )
            return false;
    }

    // Allocate memory for the new node to insert.
    LinkedNode<T>* newNode = new LinkedNode<T>();
    newNode->data = tData;

    // Special case: Are we inserting after the last node?
    if( current == mLast )
    {
        newNode->next = 0;
        mLast = newNode;
    }
    // No, else link in new node after the current node.
    else
    {
        newNode->next = current->next;
        newNode->next->prev = newNode;
    }

    newNode->prev = current;
    current->next = newNode;

    return true;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertFirst(T tData)
{
    LinkedNode<T>* newNode = new LinkedNode<T>();
    newNode->data = tData;

    // If the list is empty, then this is the first and last node and doesn't have a previous pointer.
    if( isEmpty() )
        mLast = newNode;
    // If the list is not empty, the new node becomes the previous node of the current first node.
    else
        mFirst->prev = newNode;

    // The new node's next pointer is the old first pointer. May be null if this is the first node being added to the list.
    newNode->next = mFirst;

    //The new node becomes the first node.
    mFirst = newNode;   
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertLast(T tData)
{
    LinkedNode<T>* newNode = new LinkedNode<T>();
    newNode->data = tData;

    if( isEmpty() )
        mFirst = newNode;
    else
        mLast->next = newNode;

    newNode->prev = mLast;

    mLast = newNode;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::removeFirst()
{

    if( !isEmpty() )
    {
        LinkedNode<T>* current = mFirst;

        if( mFirst == mLast )
        {
            mFirst->next = 0;
            mLast->prev = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            mFirst = current->next;
            mFirst->prev = 0;
        }

        delete current;
        current = 0;
    }   
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::removeLast()
{
    if( !isEmpty() )
    {
        LinkedNode<T>* current = mLast;

        if( mFirst == mLast )
        {
            mFirst = 0;
            mLast = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            mLast = current->prev;
            mLast->next = 0;
        }

        delete current;
        current = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(T removalCandidate)
{
    LinkedNode<T>* current = mFirst;

    if( isEmpty() )
    {
        cout << "List is empty!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while( current->data != removalCandidate )
        {
            if( current->data == removalCandidate )
            {
                break;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    if( current == mFirst )
        removeFirst();
    else if ( current == mLast )
        removeLast();
    else
    {
        // Create two linked nodes to access the next and prev nodes.
        LinkedNode<T>* left  = current->prev;
        LinkedNode<T>* right = current->next;

        left->next = right;
        right->prev = left;
    }

    delete current;
    current = 0;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::destroy()
{
    // Is there at least one node in the list?
    if( mFirst != 0 )
    {
        // Get a pointer to the first node.
        LinkedNode<T>* current = mFirst;

        // Loop until we reach the end of list.
        while( current != 0 )
        {
            // Save the current node.
            LinkedNode<T>* oldNode = current;

            // Move to next node.
            current = current->next;

            // Delete saved node.
            delete oldNode;
            oldNode = 0;
        }
    }

    mFirst = 0;
}
```

Then I have also written a stack and queue class, and I test them both to see whether a string is a palindrome. That all works. However when it runs the destroy method in the list class, it throws a: block type is valid(pHead->nBlockUse) error on the

```
delete oldNode;
```

line.

Queue code:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
public:
    Queue(){};

    ~Queue()
    {
        mList.destroy();
    }

    T& getFirst()
    {
        assert( !isEmpty() );
        return mList.getFirst()->data;
    }

    bool isEmpty( void )
    {
        return mList.isEmpty();
    }

    void push( T newElement )
    {
        mList.insertLast( newElement );
    }

    void pop()
    {
        mList.removeFirst();
    }

private:
    LinkedList<T> mList;
};
```

Stack code:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(){};

    ~Stack()
    {
        mList.destroy();    
    }

    T& getTopItem()
    {
        // Throw error if list is empty.
        assert( !isEmpty() );

        return mList.getLast()->data;
    }

    bool isEmpty( void )
    {
        return mList.isEmpty(); 
    }

    void push( T newElement )
    {
        mList.insertLast( newElement );
    }

    void pop()
    {
        mList.removeLast();
    }

private:
    LinkedList<T> mList;
};
```

Main code:

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Stack<char> strStack;
    Queue<char> strQueue;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    string input = "";
    getline(cin, input);

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i )
    {
        strStack.push( input[i] );
        strQueue.push( input[i] );
    }

    bool isPalindrome = true;

    // FIX PALINDROME AND ASSERTION FAIL

    for( unsigned int j = 0; j < input.length(); ++j )
    {
        if( strStack.getTopItem() != strQueue.getFirst() )
        {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break; // Exit for loop early.
        }

        // Get rid of next element out.
        strStack.pop();
        strQueue.pop();
    }

    cout << input << " is palindrome: " << isPalindrome << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure why, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the function you posted. Please post a complete example that lets us reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Cypras Can't do anything more than guess unless you post the code that has the error. I would guess you are not following the rule of three, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: This error occurs when you `delete` something which is allocated on the stack instead of heap. Can you show how are you adding new nodes into the list?

Comment: Check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397545/block-type-is-valid-phead-nblockuse-error) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460352/block-type-is-valid-phead-nblockuse-on-delete-command)

I think you haven't created the destructor of the class `LinkedNode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `removeFirst` function: When you remove the last node in the list (i.e. `mFirst == mLast` is `true`) you set the node link pointers to `0`, and then you delete the node. Now both `mFirst` and `mLast` points to a deleted node!

Instead of setting the `next` and `prev` links to `0`, you should set `mFirst` and `mLast` to `0`. Just like you already do in `removeLast`.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I did that..damnit!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not setting mFirst to NULL (0) right before the destroy() method returns. If you call destroy() more than once, you'll hit this kind of crt assertion as a result of attempting to delete a pointer twice.  The queue class calls mList.destroy in its destructor, but the destructor of mList will call destroy again.

Comment: Destroy is called twice, once to delete the stacks list, and again to delete the queues list.

Comment: If you are calling destroy more than once on the same instance of your class, then that is your bug.  Set mFirst to NULL right before destroy returns.

Comment: Note - it almost always a good idea to assign a variable or class member to null if it has been deleted.

Comment: I am right. You are explicitly calling destroy in your queue class. But the linked list destructor also calls destroy.

Comment: So what do I need to do? Because I do the same in stack and that doesn't throw an error if I comment out all the queue code in main.

Comment: The last line of destroy needs to set both mFirst and mLast to NULL.

Comment: @selbie Are you sure the code isn't already doing what you suggested? I see `mFirst = 0;` on the last line of the destroy method.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you say that mLast needs to be zeroed: just setting mFirst = 0 looks like it's sufficient to ensure the any next call to destroy will do nothing.

Comment: I added that after selbie suggested it, so do I even need queue and stack to call list destroy to delete mList or not?